# Installing Slowmovideo on 14.04 when only Saucy package is available

Tags: ppa, slowmovideo

i like to install Slowmovideo. But on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~brousselle/+archive/ubuntu/slowmovideo) there is no ppa for ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty). The latest supported ppa is for 13.10.

What options (if any) do I have to install the software on my ubuntu 14.04?

The doku for compiling the software says for the required packages:

```
apt-get install build-essential cmake git ffmpeg libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libswscale-dev libqt4-dev freeglut3-dev libglew1.5-dev libsdl1.2-dev libjpeg-dev libopencv-video-dev libopencv-highgui-dev opencv-dev
```

But ubuntu normaly uses avconv. I'm not shure if i brake any other video or image editing software by installing those packages.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found this helpful [almost completed fork for Debian *Jessie*](https://github.com/slowmoVideo/slowmoVideo/issues/18) after setting about building slowmoVideo under Ubuntu 14.04 myself. Try downloading valgit's code, then making a build directory in the same directory as the src directory, cd-ing into it, and then executing,

```
cmake ../src -DUSE_QTKIT=FALSE -DENABLE_TESTS=FALSE
```

The rest of the instructions are the same as those appearing in the *Compiling* section of the [slowmoVideo website](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/download.php) i.e.,

```
make -j3
sudo make install
```

This way everything builds fine for me, though I still get an error associated with finding libbamtools when CMake runs verify_app. The application itself is working fine, however. Thanks to tektektek and valgit for allowing this program to be built under 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

There is an instruction for installing slowmovideo [here](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/download.php)

it works for me

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libswscale-dev libqt4-dev freeglut3-dev libglew1.5-dev libsdl1.2-dev libjpeg-dev libopencv-video-dev libopencv-highgui-dev libopencv-dev ffmpeg
git clone git://github.com/slowmoVideo/slowmoVideo.git
cd slowmoVideo/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake -DENABLE_TESTS=FALSE ../src
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score -2):

You can compile it from source using [the code from Github](https://github.com/slowmoVideo/slowmoVideo).
Tutorial is provided on the page.

Comment: Hi. I'm a bit unsure how to compile it correctly. Because the doku says it requires ffmpeg. But as far as I know ubuntu uses avconv. I am concerned if i brake other video- or imageediting software. I have edited my question to state this concerns. Thank you.

Comment: It will run with `avconv` aswell.